# What is the procedure to update virtualenv installation of tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently using the virtualenv intallation of tensorflow version r0.7. I would like to upgrade to r0.9 in virtualenv. What ia the procedure to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work :

```
# Once inside your virtualenv
(venv) $ pip uninstall -qy tensorflow
(venv) $ pip install -U https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

That is, assuming you want the cpu version and using Python 2.7. Look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) for other versions of the pip packages.